# Problem on function definition

Tags: functions, definition

I'm trying to solve this problem about functions: "Explain why $x^2-4=0$ is not a real function of real variable."

I have yet solved many similar problems, but now i have a doubt; is my solution correct ?

I give this solution to the problem:

1 - First of all, i search all the values of $x$ that satisfies $x^2-4 = 0$, obtaining obviously $x=-2\vee x=2$. I make this step in order to make the epression $x^2-4=0$ true.
This step is a sort of domain calulation.

2 - For every value of $x$ obtained in step 1, i check if exists one and only one value of $y$ (function definition); obviously the absence of the variable $y$ make it possible to assume any value.

3 - For one value of the domain $\lbrace-2,2\rbrace$ $y$ is not uniquely determined, so the relation $x^2-4=0$ is not a function.

Do you find this explanation correct ?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: $x^2-4=0$ is an equation, not a function.

Comment: You could say something like 'the expression does not denote a set of ordered pairs so cannot be a function'. Any function is a (specific) set of ordered pairs.

Comment: The question is "do you find this explanation correct?" but the explanation is contained in the solution in your first step above.  Steps 2 and 3 are unnecessary (and even false since, as you say, there is no $y$).

Comment: *[Can “doubt” sometimes mean “question”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429)*

Answer (score 0):

Well we can say that the co-domain of this function is $\{0\}$ because $y=0$,we can say that domain is $\{-2,2\}$,since $\{-2,2\}$ is not an subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains an open set,thus $x^2-4=0$ is not a real function of real variable.